# Is it possible to get a primary route-outlet param in a secondary outlet Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been trying to get a secondary route outlet from a named route using the route ActivatedRoute module. e.g

current url:  `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/contraceptives/(assessment:5991780301d88a211e86e012//details:599062793f86454d43896255)`

outlets:

```
<div class="col m4 z-depth-3">
     <router-outlet name="details"></router-outlet>
 </div>
 <div class="col m4 z-depth-3">
     <router-outlet name="assessment"></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

component:

How can I get the details params in this current outlet and component?

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
  }
```

Comment: you need to [traverse activated route](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent)

Answer (score -1):

I manage to found a way:

```js
constructor(router:Router){
    RouterLinks.events(event=>{
        // here i am subscribing to the events
        const primaryRouter = event.state.root.firstChild;
        // where first child is the primary router-outlet
    })
}
```